# Android Background Drawable Not Working in Button Since Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, material-design, android-drawable, android-button, android-styles

I find out that since Android Studio 4.1 I cannot change the background color of a `Button` by setting color on its `android:background`, just no effect. And custom `Drawable` is not working as well.

**My background `Drawable`:**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1.5dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <corners
        android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

**My `Button`:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add To Cart"
    android:background="@drawable/background3"/>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Does your activity's theme inherit from `Theme.MaterialComponents`? If so, that seems to be the source of the problem, based on some light testing. Try switching to a `Theme.AppCompat`-based theme.

Comment: @CommonsWare it works! Thank you! But is it a bug or intentional design? Just don't get it.

Comment: I suspect strongly that it is an intentional design decision, but I need to do more research on this. The Material Components for Android is a "highly opinionated" library, so I am not surprised that they are doing something that breaks some standard widget attributes like `android:background`. What disappoints me is that they made it the default in the Android Studio new-project wizard for some (all?) templates.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for the info. Helped save a ton of time.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The Android Studio 4.1 new-project wizard, for many of its templates, has the project use the Material Components for Android library. And, it sets up the default theme to be based on `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar`.

A side effect of this is that any `<Button>` elements in a layout get turned into `MaterialButton` widgets, not regular `Button` widgets. `MaterialButton` ignores `android:background`.

If all you want to do is to change the color, use `android:backgroundTint` or change the `colorPrimary` attribute in the theme.

If you want a button that has a custom background, *and* your theme is set up to use `Theme.MaterialComponents`, you could switch the XML element in the layout to be `<android.widget.Button>` instead of `<Button>`. This should cause the Material Components for Android to ignore that element, and you can manipulate this button normally with respect to XML attributes.

Comment: for the rescue once again!

Comment: this answer is correct, `android.widget.Button` is what worked for me!

Answer (score 72):

**UPDATE 03/2021**

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"    //just need this
android:background="@drawable/background_button"
```

---

Ok, since `MaterialButton` is the default `Button` starting from Android Studio 4.1, we can modify the shape by using `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute.

**1. Create a Custom Style in `themes.xml`:**

```
<style name="leaf">
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">70%</item>           //can specify corner position
    <!--<item name="cornerFamilyTopLeft">cut</item>-->
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">70%</item>
    <!--<item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>-->
</style>
```

**2. Apply Style in `Material Button`:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Show"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/leaf" />        //here
```

**Result:**

[image]

- Helpful video:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jihLJ0oVmGo

Comment: app:backgroundTint="@null" - this! thank you!

Comment: app:backgroundTint="@null" - Made me my day +1

Comment: Great. Both `app:backgroundTint="@null"` and the MaterialButton Style works well. Thanks.

Comment: Note that we should use `app:backgroundTint`, not `android:backgroundTint`!

Answer (score 15):

Add only this:
app:backgroundTint="@null"

Comment: This works but each button than needs to have it. Is there a way to apply it in styles

Answer (score 5):

By setting `app:backgroundTint="@null"`
your material button will not be rounded any more.
To make it round and setting linear gradient color etc, Add this into drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/lightBlue" />

            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <gradient android:endColor="#FFD374" android:startColor="#FFBC68" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/lightBlue" />

            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <gradient android:endColor="#FFBC68" android:startColor="#FFD374" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

goto xml file and add it like this

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        ...........
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_gradient"
        ..........
        />
```

Note: Edit it according to your need...

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me, hope it works for others as well.
Just set `null` to `backgroundTint`.

`android:backgroundTint="@null"`.

Comment: This one should be ```app:backgroundTint="@null"```

Comment: @Masum, thanks! I didn't notice `app:` in upper answers.

Answer (score 1):

I found easiest solution in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_1H52FEqII

Just go to themes.xml under values folder in project window and change the MaterialComponents to AppCompact in both themes and button start working as normal as it was in past.

Existing: Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar
After Modification: Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar

Comment: This has been mentioned in the comments :)