# Why I can't change Textview or Button color in android studio 4.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated my android studio from 4.0 to 4.1.3.I couldn't change my TextView color
as well as Button background color.

[image]

Here is my kotlin code of MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.tvMain.setText("Register")
        binding.tvMain.setTextColor(R.color.black)
        binding.tvMain.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: you declare in your xml and u doing same in your java code. what do u mean to achieve ??both are same thats why u cant see the changes,

Comment: try to change changed "Register to "Registration" in java file

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Hey @D_K I declair both side because ,XML side is not working so try kotlin backend side but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Background Drawable Not Working in Button Since Android Studio 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722733/android-background-drawable-not-working-in-button-since-android-studio-4-1)

Answer (score 0):

Do change the Primary color in your theme style for the button background color.
Do change the text color in xml as android:textColor-"your color in # format"