# Cannot change XML button background color as expected

Tags: android, xml, button

I tried to change the background colors of buttons in an android project but it seems ineffective

This is the xml code of a button:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/comma"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:background="@drawable/button_border"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                android:text="."
                android:textColor="#7ff5f2"
                android:textSize="120px" />
```

My drawable resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="092c32"
        android:centerColor="#026a6d"
        android:endColor="#092c32"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#35f5f2" />
</shape>
```

[This is my expected button background color in my drawable resource file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VodJN.png)

[This is the app design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW5kz.png)

You can see the button background color above looks similar to the default purple, except there's a gradient, which I think related to the gradient in my drawable resource file.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722733/android-background-drawable-not-working-in-button-since-android-studio-4-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve the problem

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/comma"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:text="."
        android:textColor="#7ff5f2"
        android:textSize="120px" />
        />
```

Notice the change in the first line.