# Android studio overriding my custom button design

Tags: android

I have a custom button drawable in my android studio project (white border and transparent) and I'm using `app:background="@drawable/button_custom"` in the button xml. For some reason android studio is overriding it to a red button which is the primary theme colour. I can't work out why this is happening.

I've tried setting the background colour to transparent on the button but that just removes the borders

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AppCompatButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatButton)

An AppCompatButton is simply a [Button][2] which supports compatible features on older versions of the platform.

**Or**

You can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839917/19610655